# Why is filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL showing this string as a valid URL?

Tags: php, url, filter-var

The input string is:

```
https://lh
```

however, with:

```
var_dump(filter_var('https://lh', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) // string(10) "https://lh"
```

for some reason the above string is classed as a valid URL. I have read another SO post saying that `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` is not restricted to the `http` protocol but surely the above link is not a valid URL for any protocol.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Whats your problem with this url? Is it because, it's only a tld?

Comment: @Philipp yes, I was under the impression that it wouldn't be classed as URL. I guess not. What viable alternatives are there if I wanted to weed this sort of input out?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by this sort of input? If `https://localhost` isn't valid, would `https://localhost.com` be valid?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I would presume that would be valid yes. My understanding is URL / URL formation isn't very good therefore at a glance the URL I provided above would definitely not be valid in my eyes. I guess the pertinent question now would be what makes a URL "valid"?

Comment: LH is the country code for Lithuania. There's nothing preventing the country from operating a webserver whose URL is just their country code.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I appreciate the links. Will look them over.

Comment: I've always had trouble with those filters, which is why I don't use them anymore (for a long time) and usually resort to using a regex.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah, I try to avoid regex solution as I generally don't get them all the time but I guess it'll have to do now.

Comment: @Script47 Even `'https://2'` is considered as valid; I don't get that. `2` being an integer (or any other integer for that matter or single letter) and being a single character isn't available as any TLD. Regex's are a bit more work but worth it I find.

Comment: It's just checking the syntax, not whether or not it's something that's actually likely to exist. If you want to filter it further after that you could use `parse_url` and check the parts for whatever you want to be there. (like see if `PHP_URL_HOST` has a dot in it or something like that)

Comment: Try calling [`parse_url()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and performing additional validation steps on the individual pieces. Be warned: You seem to have quite a few incorrect assumptions about what valid URLs and hostnames can look like.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner as others have stated, a valid URL doesn't have to use a FQDN - it can use just a host name. `protocol://host:port/path/filename.foo?arguments` Protocol and host name are the only things required to initiate a connection, only critical part on the host name is that the client has to be able to resolve it - hosts file, dns, dns with appended search domain(s), etc ...

Comment: @ivanivan Right, that makes sense; I understand now (thanks). I think I may not have grasped the question then. Unless the OP is looking for security instead, for example: [filtering email addresses](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner even then those filters are making the assumption that mail is intended for internet delivery. Granted, 99.9% of the time, that is correct.  But I get mail at `ivan@darkstar` all the time from my cron jobs.  Again, `user@resolvablehost`.  The filters don't check for perfect conformity to RFCs - they check what most people consider to be conformity to the RFCs as they apply 
 to "common" public internet use.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so lots of comments later with some digression and no posted answer.

Therefore...

A valid URL doesn't have to use a FQDN - it can use just a host name. `protocol://host:port/path/filename.foo?arguments` Protocol and host name are the only things required to initiate a connection, only critical part on the host name is that the client has to be able to resolve it - hosts file, dns, dns with appended search domain(s), etc

If any of the other commenters feel the need to edit, etc. feel free.